# Call retrofit inside other mathod and return result to main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

write this code :

```
fun getStoreTitles():List<sample> {
        var responseResult:List<sample>
        responseResult= listOf(sample("","",""))
        val service = getRetrofitInstance()!!.create(GetDataService::class.java)
        val call = service.getAllPhotos()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<sample>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<sample>>, response: Response<List<sample>>) {
                responseResult=response.body()!!
                var t=0
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<sample>>, t: Throwable) {
                /*progressDoalog.dismiss()*/
                //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        });
        return responseResult
}
```

and want to call that method from main activity with this way:

```
var responseResult:List<sample>
val FrameWork=StoreTitle()
responseResult=FrameWork.getStoreTitles()
```

when run the app,retrofit run the successful but nothing return to the responseResult and that is null,i think retrofit run other thread and that's reason.how can i solve that problem?

Comment: api will call on background thread and it's will returns response in onResponse() method. so you will get always null value because method `getStoreTitles()` will return value before api getting success.

Comment: use callback for retrieve api results

Comment: @RajasekaranM how can i use callback?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your api call method:

```
fun getStoreTitles(callback : Callback<List<sample>>) {
    var responseResult:List<sample>
    responseResult= listOf(sample("","",""))
    val service = getRetrofitInstance()!!.create(GetDataService::class.java)
    val call = service.getAllPhotos()
    call.enqueue(callback);

}
```

you have to call like this :

```
val FrameWork=StoreTitle()
FrameWork.getStoreTitles(object : Callback<List<sample>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<sample>>, response: Response<List<sample>>) {
         val responseResult : List<sample>? =response.body()      
         //handle your success
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<sample>>, t: Throwable) {
             //handle your failure
        }
    })
```

Comment: why creating a new callback interface when you can use Retrofit's `Callback` (the one you need to provide to the `enqueue` method?

Comment: good question but he handled his api call in separate class that's why

Comment: true, but since the other class must implement `APICallback` in your example, why not implementing Retrofit's `Callback` directly? Conceptually they're doing the same stuff, i.e. handling the response/failure

Comment: yes you are right,I'm not think about it. thanks :-) will update answer

Comment: @RajasekaranM in this line --> <List<sample>> responseResult=response.body()!! get Function invocation 'List<sample>(...)' expected

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi check now